# Closure How to use instead of the class method?

Tags: php, class, methods, closures

How to write code that works in the following example without `__get` and `__set`.Everything else can.

```
class A {
    // What code to write here?
}

$a = new A();

$a->setName = function(A $a, $value)
{
    $a->name = $value;
};

$a->getName = function(A $a)
{
    return $a->name;
};

$a->setName('Vasya');
echo $a->getName1();
```

Comment: This seems wrong somehow...

Comment: @Jeremy  why,This concept is used by all well-known frameworks.for example Laravel routing

Comment: No... Not like that.... Read up `Illuminate\Routing\Route` and you will understand what is going on and also in Laravel the call is static like so: `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});`. Don't think this looks any closer to what you've just done or posted ;-)

Comment: @Poiz 21 yes,but he get callback as params,and use such closure

Comment: The only way I can think about this is with either `__get` and `__set` or `__call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friends, I solved the problem

```
class A {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        try{
            if(property_exists($this,$name) && is_callable($this->$name)){
                $arguments = array_merge([__CLASS__=>$this],$arguments);
                return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $arguments);
            }
            else{
                throw new Exception($name.' is not a callable');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}

$a = new A();

$a->setName = function(A $a, $value)
{
    $a->name = $value;
};

$a->getName = function(A $a)
{
    return $a->name;
};

$a->setName('John');
echo $a->getName();
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php#117504